# How to add an argument to a va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have the following code:

```
int __dmasprintf (char **s, const char *format, ...) {

    char buf[512];
    va_list arg;
    int ret;
    va_start(arg,format);
    ret = vsprintf(buf, format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    *s = strdup(buf);
    if (*s == NULL) return -1;
    return 0;   
}
```

I want to add an argument to the `va_list` `arg` before calling `vsprintf()` because my `format` contains 1 extra argument at the end.

How to add an argument (for example `char * myarg`) to the the `va_list` `arg`?

Or is it possible to pass `vsprintf()` a customized list?

Comment: These are macros. You are not sopposed to modify the list.

Comment: @Olaf Is it possible to pass to the vsprintf a customized list

Comment: Is your code compiled by a [tag:c] or [tag:c++] compiler, or does it have to work in both?

Comment: Basically, you cannot. If I were faced with such a task, I'd try to 1) reconsider the design; 2) failing that, walk `format` backwards looking for `%` signs until I find the last format specifier, truncate it, call `vsprintf` with abbreviated format, then call `sprintf` with the remaining piece of `format` and my extra parameter, appending to the end of the previously formatted buffer.

Comment: @Yakk the code is compiled by a c compiler

Comment: Can't you just add the extra argument to the call?  After all, you've modified the format for the extra argument, why not just modify the caller?

Comment: @MOHAMED then why did you tag it [tag:c++]?  I mean, solving this problem in c++ is easy, but if you have a c problem, that is a useless tag.  You have 13000 rep...

Comment: @cup I can not add the extra arg to the call.

Comment: What about appending the last argument in a separate call to `sprintf(buf + ret, ...)`?

Comment: Thats not how `va_list` works, but you can always pass `buf` as a `%s` parameter to a second iteration of `sprintf()` where you can pass as many more parameters you like, or if its something to be appended to the end, you just keep writing to the same buffer, like `sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), "%s %i", "more stuff", 123);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no direct way to do that. There is a reason for that : the stdarg macros take the address in the stack of the last known parameter, and then directly iterate the stack.

If you can use macros, @Useless provided a nice solution - beware, macros can have side effects when you pass variables pre- or post-fixed with `++` or `--`.

If you want to avoid macros, you will have to write your own variant of vsprintf. No problem for it, just find a source for C stdlib ([GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) could be a nice start point) and be brave ... hope you can use macros !

Answer (score 8):

You can't.

You either need to make two `vsprintf` (surely *`vsnprintf`*?) calls, or replace your function with a variadic macro, like

```
#define __dmasprintf(S, FMT, ...) ( \
    (*S = do_dmasprintf(FMT, __VA_ARGS__, my_arg)) == NULL ? -1 : 0)

char *do__dmasprintf (const char *format, ...) {

    char buf[512];
    va_list arg;
    int ret;
    va_start(arg,format);
    ret = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, arg);
    va_end(arg);

    char *s = strdup(buf);
    return s;   
}
```

Notes:

1. I replaced `vsprintf` with `vsnprintf`. There's no reason to use the former here (or pretty much anywhere else)
2. you ignore `ret`. Should you?
3. I kept the macro argument layout similar to the original, but since `__VA_ARGS__` must be one-or-more arguments (it can't be empty), that means at least one argument is required after `FMT`. Just remove the `FMT` argument entirely if you want to allow zero arguments after it.

Comment: "it can't be empty" true, though GCC allows it as an extension

Comment: There's a lot of reason to prefer `vsprintf()` over `vsnprintf()`: The later will truncate long messages. This may be desired to avoid DOS attacks by flooding log files, but for any application that does not need to protect against its own user (most local processes), truncating output messages is an anti-feature. Such processes should try their best not to fail on any user input, with the only limitation being that they might be killed due to excessive memory consumption.

Comment: Using vsprintf allows buffer overrun, and that doesn't just bloat logfiles, it smashes the stack. Truncating messages _to fit in the space available_ is not an anti-feature IMO. Preventing stack smashing is not a failure!